# Time complexity of deleting an edge in an adjacency list

Tags: algorithm

For a graph(V,E) where V is the total number of vertices and E is the total number of edges, what is the time complexity of deleting an edge? I thought it would be O(V) worst case since the max number of edges any vertex can have is V-1. But I have been told the time complexity is O(M) where M is the number of edges a vertex has. Which is correct?

Comment: Is it a multigraph?

Comment: No, it isn't a multigraph.

Comment: Then it seems like O(M) == O(V) like you say. Worst case scenario we have a complete graph and delete an edge.

Comment: I asked this somewhere else, and was told  that it is not O(V) but O(E) (they changed E to mean the number of edges in the current vertex's linked list so O(M) basically). And was told O(M) and O(V) aren't the same.

Comment: Yeah here you go: https://www.reddit.com/r/algorithms/comments/i7haxy/what_is_the_time_complexity_for_removing_an_edge/g120nl1?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x

There's a few people saying O(V) is wrong and then other's saying it's correct, so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the structure of your graph.

If you choose to implement the graph as an adjacency list, removing an element from a list is O(V), since you may have to iterate through the list.

However, you can implement the graph as a list of sets (each set being the list of adjacent nodes of a node), and hence the time complexity can be O(logV) if the set is sorted or O(1) if it is a hash set.

If your graph is represented as an adjacency matrix, it is also O(1), since you just have to erase E[u][v] and E[v][u].

Comment: OP does specify adjacency list in the title.